# How to get a new array from a specific array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How do I get a new array from a specific array?

I don't known how to handle an Array like this:

```
let arr1 = [
  {name: 'a', age: 1},
  {name: 'a', age: 2},
  {name: 'a', age: 3},
  {name: 'b', age: 1},
  {name: 'b', age: 2}
  {name: 'b', age: 3}
  {name: 'c', age: 1}
  {name: 'c', age: 2}
  ...
]
```

"I want this result: from each item with the same `name`, pick biggest `age` value"

```
let arr2 = [
  {name: 'a', age: 3},
  {name: 'b', age: 3},
  {name: 'c', age: 2} 
  ...
]
```

Comment: `const arr2 = arr1.filter( a => a.age === Math.max( ...arr1.filter( b => b.name === a.name ).map( ({ age }) => age ) ) );`

Comment: I think that's what you want, but I'm on mobile so I can't post an answer with code easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of `reduce` and `Object.values`

```js
 const arr1 = [
  {name: 'a', age: 1},
  {name: 'a', age: 2},
  {name: 'a', age: 3},
  {name: 'b', age: 1},
  {name: 'b', age: 2},
  {name: 'b', age: 3},
  {name: 'c', age: 1},
  {name: 'c', age: 2},
]

const maxNames = arr1.reduce((maxNamesObject, item) => {
  const { name, age } = item
  const maxItem = maxNamesObject[name]
  if (!maxItem || age > maxItem.age) {
    maxNamesObject[name] = item
  }
  return maxNamesObject
}, {})

const output = Object.values(maxNames)

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use `filter` to select all items with the highest `age` for their `name`.

```js
let arr1 = [{name:'a',age:1},{name:'a',age:2},{name:'a',age:3},{name:'b',age:1},{name:'b',age:2},{name:'b',age:3}];

const biggest = arr1.reduce((a, { name, age }) => {
  a[name] = a[name] || age;
  age > a[name] ? a[name] = age : a[name];
  return a;
}, {});

let arr2 = arr1.filter(({ name, age }) => biggest[name] == age);

console.log(arr2);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Comment: Much cleaner than mine... +1 :-D

Comment: Nice trick with the console snippet btw, I wasn't aware you could do that!

Comment: Yeah - that just lets the console output become bigger if it's required

Comment: That doesn't answer his question. He wants the biggest number. It isn't necessarily 3.

Comment: Biggest number - my bad, thought it was three. Fixed @BillyHudson.

Comment: Better @BillyHudson?

Comment: @JackBashford That snippet doesn't seem to work if I change the input array to something like `a:1, a:2, a:3, b:1, b:2, b:4`, etc.

Comment: Hmm - oh I see, so the highest of *each `name`*. That's better - I'll fix it.

Comment: Okay fixed. Could those who downvoted please remove their votes, as the answer now works.

Answer (score 0):

Extracted from this answer: [How to filter object array based on attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes)

You can use the [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method:

```
let arr2 = arr1.filter(function (obj) {
  return obj.age === 3;
});
```

Comment: sorry! this not my want, arr1 just a stucture like this, I have edit my new question!

Comment: @EVDS - you need to expand further in your question. Both posted answers will filter the array and return a new array based on the specified filter

Comment: @BenCarey what happens to age === 2 || age === 1 as the higest of it key?(name)

Comment: @BenCarey Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

This is a more beautiful solution:

```js
let arr1 = [
  {name: 'a', age: 1},
  {name: 'a', age: 2},
  {name: 'a', age: 3},
  {name: 'b', age: 1},
  {name: 'b', age: 2},
  {name: 'b', age: 3},
  {name: 'c', age: 1},
  {name: 'c', age: 2},
]

arr2 = Array.from(new Set(arr1.map(e => e.name))).map(e => { 
    return {
        name: e,
        age: Math.max(...arr1.filter(ee => ee.name == e).map(ee => ee.age))
    }
})

console.log(arr2)
```

> Blockquote

Answer (score 0):

my solution:

```js
const arr1 = [
  {name: 'a', age: 1},
  {name: 'a', age: 2},
  {name: 'a', age: 3},
  {name: 'b', age: 1},
  {name: 'b', age: 2},
  {name: 'b', age: 3},
  {name: 'c', age: 1},
  {name: 'c', age: 2},
]

let arr2 = arr1.reduce((acc, item) => {      
  let objectExists = acc.find(e => e.name === item.name)
  if (!objectExists) acc.push(item)
  else if (objectExists.age < item.age) {
      acc[acc.indexOf(objectExists)].age = item.age
  }
  return acc
}, [])

console.log(arr2)
```

Answer (score -1):

I didn't notice you update the question. This is not the most pro code.

```js
  let arr1 = [
  {name: 'a', age: 1}, {name: 'a', age: 2}, {name: 'a', age: 3},
  {name: 'b', age: 1}, {name: 'b', age: 2}, {name: 'b', age: 3},
  {name: 'c', age: 1}, {name: 'c', age: 2} ];

  let names = [];
  let output = [];

  for(obj of arr1){
   if (!names.includes(obj.name)) names.push(obj.name);
  }

  for(obj of names){
    let current = arr1.filter(x => x.name === obj)
                      .reduce((a,b) => a.age > b.age ? a : b);

    output.push(current);
  }

    console.log(output);
```